# PHP's PDO execute() vs. fetch()?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a quick question that I hope has a quick and clear answer.

On php.com's manual, it states that execute() after binding the values to a prepared query will return true on success and false on failure. Simple enough.

I just wanted to make sure I had this clear. The values returned on execute() correspond to direct errors. For instance, if the database somehow went down after a successful connect, and the query could not be executed - or some other extraordinary issue.

Consider some code:

```
    protected function territoryCheck($numberOut)
    {
        $this->numberOut = $numberOut;

        //Execute test
        $this->checkConnect();
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT t_id FROM Territory WHERE t_id = :param1")
        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->numberOut);
        $stmt->execute();

        //Determine value of test
        if($stmt == FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }
```

I am rather sure that this will not operate as I want. The point is to see if t_id exists in the database based on whether there is a corresponding value to the parameter. In that case, I need to use $stmt->fetch(). Am I correct in saying that?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Along the same lines, would it be prudent - or I should say best practice - to put

```
//Execute test
        $this->checkConnect();
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT t_id FROM Territory WHERE t_id = :param1")
        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->numberOut);
        $stmt->execute();
```

within a try-catch since PDO returns exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. `$stmt->execute()` return `false` only when it failed to execute the query. It won't return `false` with empty result set. So you need to use `fetch()` to check the result, `fetch()` return `false` for empty result set.

And for the exceptions,  PDO will throw exception only when you set the exception mode for the methods `execute()` etc. But `new PDO(...)` will throw exception no matter whether the exception mode is set.

Comment: Which version would utilizes the new PDO? One reference work in particular states PHP PDO triggers errors in the form of an exception - and it simply states PHP 5.