# Moving foreach loop inside the while loop is not working in the expected way

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I need some help and clarification about how to do it all correctly, since it look like that I am doing it in the wrong and not most optimal way so it wasted my server resource.

Here is my code, which works, but I think it could be optimized for much faster performance if `foreach` is placed inside the `while` loop, instead of wrapping it like this :

```
$link_id = explode(',', $ref_links_id);
    foreach($link_id as $key => $value){
        $additional_links_query = 'SELECT * FROM additional_links WHERE id = '.$value.' ORDER BY ID asc';
        $res = $db->prepare($additional_links_query);
        $res->execute();
        while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
            $li_text = ($info['_ad_text'] == NULL)? '' : ' - '.$info['_ad_text'];
            $li_target = ($info['_ad_url_target'] == NULL)? '' : ' target="'.$info['_ad_url_target'].'"' ;
            $li_nofollow = ($info['_ad_nofollow'] == 1)? ' rel="nofollow"' : '';
            $li_cont = '<li><a href="'.$info['_ad_url'].'"'.$li_target.$li_nofollow.'>'.$info['_ad_anchor'].'</a>'.$li_text.'</li>';
        print<<<END
        $li_cont\n
        END;
    }
}
```

My initial approach was to place `foreach` loop inside the `while` loop, which could have save the round backs, but every attempt of mine has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to remove one of the `foreach` or `while` loop from your code

see this code that I remove `foreach` from PHP and add `IN` command to your SQL query:

```
$additional_links_query = 'SELECT * FROM additional_links WHERE id IN ('.implode(",", $ref_links_id).') ORDER BY ID asc';
$res = $db->prepare($additional_links_query);
$res->execute();
while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
    $li_text = ($info['_ad_text'] == NULL)? '' : ' - '.$info['_ad_text'];
    $li_target = ($info['_ad_url_target'] == NULL)? '' : ' target="'.$info['_ad_url_target'].'"' ;
    $li_nofollow = ($info['_ad_nofollow'] == 1)? ' rel="nofollow"' : '';
    $li_cont = '<li><a href="'.$info['_ad_url'].'"'.$li_target.$li_nofollow.'>'.$info['_ad_anchor'].'</a>'.$li_text.'</li>';
print<<<END
$li_cont\n
END;
```

Comment: problem is that $ref_links_id is an array and it wont work like that. What I actually needed is to move foreach inside the while loop instead of having while inside the forach loop.

Comment: okey, I change `$ref_links_id` to `implode(",", $ref_links_id)`

Comment: `IN()` requires `()` around the value list. Also note if the values are strings, this will fail, and `'A,B,C'` will need `FIND_IN_SET(id, 'A,B,C')` instead.

Comment: @AlexB won't be notified of your question unless you notify with `@AlexB` in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks like you could do this in a single query, as well as using MySQLI correctly using [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
$ref_links_arr = explode(',', $ref_links_id);

// We need a series of parameter placeholders, e.g., ?,?,?
// One for each ref_link_id, which will be used in the
// query as placeholders in the IN() clause list.
$ref_links_params = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ref_links_arr ), '?'));

// Using IN(), see the links below for the MySQL manual entry.
$additional_links_query = "
SELECT * 
FROM additional_links 
WHERE id IN($ref_links_params) 
ORDER BY ID asc
";

$res = $db->prepare($additional_links_query);
$res->execute();

// Here, we're going to replace each ? placeholder with
// a corresponding ref_link_id from $ref_links_arr.
while ($ref_link_id = array_shift($ref_links_arr)) {
    // "i" is for "integer", so if your id field is
    // string, use "s"
    $res->bind_param("i", $ref_links_id);
}

while ($info = $res->fetch()){
    $li_text = ($info['_ad_text'] == NULL)? '' : ' - '.$info['_ad_text'];
    $li_target = ($info['_ad_url_target'] == NULL)? '' : ' target="'.$info['_ad_url_target'].'"';
    $li_nofollow = ($info['_ad_nofollow'] == 1)? ' rel="nofollow"' : '';
    $li_cont = '<li><a href="'.$info['_ad_url'].'"'.$li_target.$li_nofollow.'>'.$info['_ad_anchor'].'</a>'.$li_text.'</li>';

    print "$li_cont\n";
}
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/330280/451969

Answer (score 0):

comment line

```
$res->execute();
```

because you are try to execute and fetch also.. [PHP's PDO execute() vs. fetch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488086/phps-pdo-execute-vs-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a prepared statement, you might as well bind your data before injecting to your database:

```
$additional_links_query = 'SELECT * FROM additional_links WHERE id = :value ORDER BY ID asc';
$res->bindValue(':value',$amount);
$res = $db->prepare($additional_links_query);
$res->execute();
```

If you don't want to loop through your results straight away, you could do `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. Of course, this will return an associative array which you will have to parse at a later time.

```
$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($res);
```